# EF programmatically insert many to many

Tags: entity-framework

I have table with this structure ID PK and two columns with FK for example ActivityID and ContactID.
I try programmatically insert some value in this two FK columns.
How can I do this, any help is appriciated.Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your structure - you have to get instances of Activity and of Contact and just set corresponding properties on new entity.

```
var newActivityContact = new ActivityContact();// m_Entities.CreateActivityContact(0);
newActivityContact.Activity = activityRepository.GetById(activityId);
newActivityContact.Contact = contactRepository.GetById(contactId);
m_Entities.AddToActivityContact(newActivityContact);
m_Entities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: activityRepository.GetById(activityId) Is this query to get this activity.

Comment: yes - retrieve it from your m_Entities instance like

      m_Entities.Contact.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Contact_Id == contactId);

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to get rid of primary key, set up combination of ActivityID and ContactID as PK and then recreate whole model in visual designer. Every `Activity` object will have `Contacts` navigation property and every `Contact` will have `Activities`. You will be able to add contacts to activity by calling:

```
activity.Contacts.Add(contact);
```

If you really need additional ID, it will be more complicated.

Comment: I have this two FK in datatable and i try to insert this in this rel.table on sql.